# Count occurrences of certain number in worksheet column, looking up by header row

Tags: excel

We keep track of salaries using an excel file with a tab per month:

[image: example]

50 = regular salary
100 = regular salary for double shift
30, 60 etc. are exceptions that don´t need to be considered

Now my boss wants to know who worked how often considering the normal and double shifts only. so the result should be a list(table) like Bob 50*X, 100*Y, Bill 50*X, 100*Y

What would the syntax look like? It´s possible that while Bill is B1 in January it might be that he is C1.. in another month so the solution should use the header row to do a lookup.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the formula

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B7,50)
```

will return the number of instances of the data `50` in the range `B2:B7`.

In order to find the column corresponding to a specific employee you can use `MATCH`, (e.g.) `MATCH("Bob",B1:C1,0)` which finds the exact text `Bob` in the range `B1:C1`. Now you need to change the range in your `COUNTIF` function to correspond to the column for Bob, which you can do with `OFFSET`:

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET($A$2,0,MATCH("Bob",$B$1:$C$1,0),6,1),50)
```

The number `6` in the above formula is the number of rows containing salary data - could that change? If so you could replace it with e.g. `MATCH("Tot",$B2:$A99,0)-1` which will count how many rows there are from row B to the row containing `Tot`.

Look up the functions `COUNTIF`, `MATCH` and `OFFSET` in the Excel help for more detail on how to use them.